# Sitecore Package creation Install Ver in code c#

Tags: sitecore-api

I have written code that creates packages in Sitecore ver 8 and uploads and publishes in sitecore 9. The code is done in C# create package and installing package and publishing the package.
Creating a package code was done with the help of using this link
https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/sitecore-create-package-programmatically/

installing a package was also done searching code in stack exchange. code below

```
global::Sitecore.Context.SetActiveSite("shell");
            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                using (new SyncOperationContext())
                {
                    using (new EventDisabler())
                    {
                        var db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
                        using (var dbSwitcher = new DatabaseSwitcher(db))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                global::Sitecore.Install.Framework.IProcessingContext context = new global::Sitecore.Install.Framework.SimpleProcessingContext();

                                global::Sitecore.Install.Items.IItemInstallerEvents events =
                                    new global::Sitecore.Install.Items.DefaultItemInstallerEvents(
                                    new global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.BehaviourOptions(global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallMode.Merge,
                                    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.MergeMode.Merge));

                                context.AddAspect(events);
                                global::Sitecore.Install.Files.IFileInstallerEvents events1 = new global::Sitecore.Install.Files.DefaultFileInstallerEvents(true);
                                context.AddAspect(events1);
                                var inst = new global::Sitecore.Install.Installer();

                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("MYImportRunning", "true");
                                global::Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("MY Import: Install Package start", this);
                                inst.InstallPackage(global::Sitecore.MainUtil.MapPath(path), context);
                                global::Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("My Import: Install Package end", this);
                                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("My.Running", "false");
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                global::Sitecore.Diagnostics.Error.LogError(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


 private void PublishLocations()
        {
            var publishSetting = global::Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetSetting("My.ImportPublish");

            bool publish;

            bool.TryParse(publishSetting, out publish);
            if (publish)
                PublishingHelper.PublishItem("/sitecore/content/Home/Pages", PublishMode.Smart, true, true);
        }
```

The problem I am facing is, In sitecore 8 for example, I have a page Apple, and that page has 4 versions(ver1, ver2, ver3, ver4). Version 4 being the latest version. When the package is created it gets the latest 4th version. In sitecore 9 the same page Apple has 5 versions. When the package is installed and published it only updates the  fourth version being the latest version. The 5 version is not updated because the 5 version is not there in sitecore 8 package.
My question is, is there a way when the package is installed and published in sitecore 9, it updates  the latest versions of the page in sitecore 9 or is there any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your code installs packages with the `Merge-Merge` option:

```
new global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.BehaviourOptions(
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallMode.Merge,
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.MergeMode.Merge));
```

This option instructs Sitecore to replace only matching items and versions from the package, for example if there is version 4 in the package, it will overwrite fields in the version 4 of the target item.

If you want to keep the existing item version and add the packaged content as a new version, then you should use the `Merge-Append` option:

```
new global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.BehaviourOptions(
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallMode.Merge,
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.MergeMode.Append));
```

In your example, it will keep the existing version 5 and create a version 6 with content from the package, so installed content will become the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Anna's answer and addon to that, if you want to update the latest version (version 5) with the current condition `Merge`.

```
new global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.BehaviourOptions(
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallMode.Merge,
    global::Sitecore.Install.Utils.MergeMode.Append));
```

You have to prepare a package with that version (version 5) and try to install it with the `Merge option.

Installation Options are:
[image]

Reference: [Installation Options](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/Reference/Archive/SC53%20End%20User/Package%20Designer/Adding%20Items%20and%20Files/Adding%20Dynamic%20Sources/Editing%20the%20Dynamic%20Source/Installation%20Options.html)